# function call as target in implicit rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my Makefile, I have a recipe that generates multiple files.  Something like this:

```
foo-% bar-%: foobar-%
    grep "foo" $^ > foo-$*
    grep "bar" $^ > bar-$*
```

which works as expected:

```
$ make foo-lol
grep "foo" foobar-lol > foo-lol
grep "bar" foobar-lol > bar-lol
```

In my real case, the target and prerequisite filepaths are a lot more complicated (see at the end) and used elsewhere so I placed the logic in function like so:

```
target_names = foo-$(1) bar-$(1)
```

and tried to use it on my recipe

```
$(call target_names,%): foobar-%
    grep "foo" $^ > foo-$*
    grep "bar" $^ > bar-$*
```

Which to my surprise, also worked:

```
$ make foo-lol
grep "foo" foobar-lol > foo-lol
grep "bar" foobar-lol > bar-lol
```

I don't understand why it works.  How does Make find this recipe?  I always thought that Make would go through the list of targets in all recipes. But if that's so, what is the logic behind it when instead of target filenames there is a function call?  How does Make find the right input for the function call that returns the wanted target?

---

As I mentioned, my real example is quite more complex with 8 target and 2 prerequisites:

```
target_names = \
  $(foreach tissue, $(TISSUE), \
    $(foreach chain, $(CHAIN), \
      $(foreach direction, R1 R2, \
        $(foreach read, $(filter %_$(direction)_001.fastq, $(1)), \
          $(patsubst data/%_$(direction)_001.fastq, \
                     results/%-$(tissue)-$(chain)-$(direction).fastq, \
                     $(read))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call is processed *before* the rule is added to the list of rules, you can verify this by running `make -Rpn`.

`$(call target_names,%)`

-> substitutes `foo-$(1) bar-$(1)`, where `$1` == `%`

-> returns `foo-% bar-%`

-> `foo-% bar-%: foobar-%` is added to the list of rules